# Error creating MIP problem using ompr package in R

Tags: r, optimization, knapsack-problem, mixed-integer-programming, ompr

I'm currently using the ompr and roi packages in R to solve a IP type problem.  I've managed to solve a simple version, however, I'm now trying to extend the problem, and I only want to include an item in 1 knapsack (don't allow it to appear in a knapsack more than once).  Below is an example dataset I am using (called KP):

| Itemid | ItemType | Value | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 114 | 24 |
| 2 | B | 557 | 136 |
| 3 | B | 543 | 136 |
| 4 | B | 10 | 136 |
| 5 | B | 4 | 136 |
| 6 | C | 161 | 152 |
| 7 | A | 184 | 24 |
| 8 | A | 751 | 24 |
| 9 | A | 184 | 24 |
| 10 | A | 150 | 24 |

My inital version of the knapsack I solved using the following code (and with a knapsack capacity of 240):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.glpk)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)

# Create variables from data to use in model
n <- nrow(KP)
v <- KP$Value
w <- KP$Weight
c <- 240


solution <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[i], i = 1:n, type = "binary") %>%
  set_objective(sum_expr(v[i] * x[i], i = 1:n), "max") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(w[i] * x[i], i = 1:n) <= c) %>%
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk")) %>% 
  get_solution(x[i]) 
  #filter(value > 0)

# Now join solution to original dataframe
df <- cbind(KP,capacity=240,solution[,3,drop=FALSE])
ouput <- df %>% filter(value > 0)
```

I now want to solve an extended version using a vector of capacities (200, 150).  Here is the code that I've used, now incorporating an x[i, j] binary variable that is set to 1 if item i is added to c[j]:

```
# Create variables from data to use in model
n <- nrow(KP)
v <- KP$Value
w <- KP$Weight
c <- c(240,150)
m <- length(c)

# Now solve the model
solution <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[i, j], i = 1:n,j=1:m, type = "binary") %>%
  set_objective(sum_expr(v[i] * x[i, j], i = 1:n, j=1:m), "max") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(w[i] * x[i, j], i = 1:n, j=1:m) <= c[j]) %>% #This constraint ensures that the weight of the items must be less than the capacity
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], i = 1:n, j=1:m) <= 1) %>% #This constraint ensure that an item can only be included in a single knapsack - not across multiple knapsacks
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk")) %>% 
  get_solution(x[i, j]) 
#filter(value > 0)
```

I've tried debugging the code and it is essentially the constraint that is not generating correctly (this is where the error occurs).  Here is the error I'm getting:

***Error in check_for_unknown_vars_impl(model, the_ast) :
The expression contains a variable that is not part of the model.***

I've tried all manner of things to try and get around this but can't seem to work out what is wrong with my constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that is interested, I had needed to index j on the right hand side.  So I managed to get a solution and limit each item to only being added to a knapsack once:

```
# Create variables from data to use in model
n <- nrow(KP)
v <- KP$Value
w <- KP$Weight
c <- c(240,150)
m <- length(c)

# Now solve the model
solution <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[i, j], i = 1:n,j=1:m, type = "binary") %>%
  set_objective(sum_expr(v[i] * x[i, j], i = 1:n, j=1:m), "max") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(w[i] * x[i, j], i = 1:n) <= c[j], j = 1:m) %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i, j], j = 1:m) <= 1, i=1:n) %>%
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "glpk")) %>% 
  get_solution(x[i, j]) %>%
  filter(value > 0)
```